# Open telephone default app and email app choice on click on a ListView item

Tags: android, android-listview

I have a ListView with two fields: an email address and a telephone number. How can I open the telephone default app or the email app choice dialog when I click on the email or on the number in the ListView?

Answer (score 1):

For posterity....

For what concerns the telephone app I used the following code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
String pn = "tel:" + "phone_number";
i.setData(Uri.parse(pn));
startActivity(intent);
```

For what concerns the email app choice dialog (if we have more than one email clien installed on the device) I used the following code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW); 
Uri data = Uri.parse("mailto:"+ "email_address"); 
intent.setData(data); 
startActivity(intent);
```

Hope this helps!